# BFS is there a missing parameter?

Tags: ocaml

I have the following code to perform a BFS in a graph:

```
open Queue 


type 'a node = {id: 'a; edges: 'a list}
type 'a graph = 'a node list


let bfs g s = 
    let seen = Array.make (Array.length g) false
    and treated = Queue.create() in 
    Queue.add s treated ; seen.(s) <- true ;
    let rec add_neighbors = function
    |[]                    -> ()
    |t::q when seen.(t)  -> add_neighbors q
    |t::q                  -> Queue.add t treated ; seen.(t) <- true ; add_neighbors q
    in
    try while true do 
      let s = Queue.take treated in 
      print_int s ;
      add_neighbors g.(s)
      done
    with Empty -> ()
```

The problem is that I don't understand how the function `bfs` works. At first we give the graph `g` and the first node `s`, but then the function `add_neighbors` is:

```
let rec add_neighbors = function
```

The problem here is that this function is waiting for an argument, but I don't see where in the code we give this argument to the function `add_neighbors`.

To be more precise. Let's say I have a graph `g`, and I want to perform a BFS on this graph starting at the node s.

So I call the function `bfs g s`. So here is what the function does :

- creating an array named `seen` with all entries equal to `false`
- creating a queue named `treated` in which we add the node `s`
- we update the value of the node `s` in the array `seen`. So now in the array `seen` the value of `s` is true
- Here is the problem for me. We are calling here a recursive function named `add_neighbors` but this function is here waiting for an argument but here what is the argument we are giving to this function? How the algorithm continues from here?

Comment: Can you use English type and variable names, please? The code is really hard to understand otherwise, which makes it hard for us to help.

Comment: `q` is the argument in the `ajoute_voisin q` call and `g.(s)` is the argument in the `ajoute_voisin g.(s)` call

Comment: Excuse me. I think it's better now. Actually, I don't understand with which argument we are going to call the function `add_neighbors` when we perform for the first time the function `bfs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the function does [create] an array named `seen` […], [creates] a queue named `treated` […], [and updates] the value of the node `s` in the array `seen`.
>   [Then] we are calling here a recursive function named `add_neighbors` but this function is here waiting for an argument, but what is the argument we are giving to this function?

No, `let rec add_neighbors = function` does not call the function. It *declares* the local `add_neighbors` variable with a function value, and then it allows us to use this variable `in` the following block.

> How the algorithm continues from here?

The next thing the algorithm executes is the block

```
try while true do 
  let s = Queue.take treated in 
  print_int s ;
  add_neighbors g.(s)
  done
with Empty -> ()
```

In an infinite loop, it takes the first node from the `treated` queue, prints it, and *then* calls `add_neighbors` with the what are presumably the neighbors of the node `s`. This `g.(s)` (or `Array.get g s`) call suggests that `g` is not of type `graph`, but rather an array of lists, with the array index being the node id where some edges originate and the list values being the node ids to where the edges point.

This infinite loop ends when the `Queue.take` operation throws an `Empty` exception, which is caught and handled by doing nothing. I'd say that it's better to instead write

```
while not (Queue.is_empty treated) do 
  let s = Queue.take treated in 
  print_int s ;
  add_neighbors g.(s)
done
```